# Javascript OOP issue

Tags: javascript, oop

Here's my issue. I've created a checkbox which if it's not checked , it shows an alert('Not checked') and if that box is chechked , to show the information for the person. The problem is that I don't know how to access cars[] array. It shows [object Object] instead of the brand and the year of the car.

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
            <label for="person1">PersonOne</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="person1">
</form>
      <button id="moreInfo">CLICK</button>
      <div id="info"></div>
```

JS:

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){


    var info = document.getElementById('info');

    var person1 = {
        name:'Joro',
        age:20,
        cars: [
          {
              brand:'BMW',
              year:1998,
          }  ,
          {
              brand:'Punto',
              year:2000,
          }          
        ],
        fullName: function(){
            return 'Name: ' + this.name + ' ,, ' +'Age: ' + this.age;
        }
    }

  document.getElementById('moreInfo').addEventListener('click',function(){
     if(document.myForm.checkbox.checked){
     info.innerHTML = person1.fullName() + person1.cars[1];
      } else{
          alert('not checked');
      }

  });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){


        var info = document.getElementById('info');

        var person1 = {
            name:'Joro',
            age:20,
            cars: [
              {
                  brand:'BMW',
                  year:1998
              }  ,
              {
                  brand:'Punto',
                  year:2000
              }          
            ],
            fullName: function(){
                return 'Name: ' + this.name + ' ,, ' +'Age: ' + this.age;
            },
            allCars : function(){
              var str='';
              
              this.cars.forEach(car=>{
                  
                   str += car.brand + ' ' + car.year+ '<br>';
           
              });
              return str;
            }
        }

      document.getElementById('moreInfo').addEventListener('click',function(){
         if(document.myForm.checkbox.checked){
         info.innerHTML = person1.fullName() + person1.cars[1].brand;
             info.innerHTML+='<br>allCars:   ' + person1.allCars();
          } else{
              alert('not checked');
          }

      });


    });
```

```html
    <form name="myForm">
                <label for="person1">PersonOne</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="person1">
    </form>
          <button id="moreInfo">CLICK</button>
          <div id="info"></div>
```

You have to use

```
   person1.cars[1].brand
```

or

```
   person1.cars[1].year
```

take the filed from the object

Comment: Yo , thank you man ,may I ask you one more question.How to make a function like the function i've defined to show name + age in one , instead of writing person1.age + person1.name , can I make it for example allCars: function(){ return this.cars.brand + this.cars.year;} ??? to return all the cars the person has? –

Comment: I added allCars function

Answer (score 1):

This part of line `person1.cars[1]` trying to convert the internal `car` object to string. To get the needed object properties use dot `.` or bracket `[]` notation:

```
info.innerHTML = person1.fullName() + "," + person1.cars[1].brand + "," + person1.cars[1].year;
```

or

```
info.innerHTML = person1.fullName() + "," + person1.cars[1].['brand'] + "," + person1.cars[1].['year'];
```

---

Asked method(to return all the cars the person has):

```
...
fullName: function(){
    return 'Name: ' + this.name + ' ,, ' +'Age: ' + this.age;
},
getAllCars: function(){
    var person_cars = "Cars: ";
    this.cars.forEach(function(car){
        person_cars += car.brand + "," + car.year + "; ";
    });
    return person_cars;
}
...
```

Comment: Yo , thank you man ,may I ask you one more question.How to make a function like the function i've defined to show name + age in one , instead of writing person1.age + person1.name , can I make it for example allCars: function(){ 
 return this.cars.brand + this.cars.year;} ??? to return all the cars the person has?

Answer (score 1):

In Json formatting, this is not valid :

```
      {
          brand:'BMW',
          year:1998,
      }  ,
      {
          brand:'Punto',
          year:2000,
      }
```

no `,` before the closing `}` so try to avoid it.

Comment: There's no JSON in the OP's code. There *is* an object literal, and object literals are allowed to have a trailing comma after their last property (officially in the ECMAScript 5 spec, and supported by all modern browsers).